# Unable to get the facebook access token?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm currently trying to post a url/status to my facebook page after executing a script with PHP (Codeigniter). At the moment I am getting the following error `uncaught oauthexception invalid oauth access token signature.` I know the problem is something to do with the fact my access token is wrong but no matter how much documentation I read on Facebook I can't seem to figure it out. Could someone give me a solution as to how I would get the access token?

```
        include('system/libraries/facebook.php');

    if($this->session->userdata('level') == "admin"){

        $role = $this->input->post('role');
        $company = $this->input->post('company');
        $location = str_replace( '+', ' ', $this->input->post('location') );
        $category = str_replace( '+', ' ', $this->input->post('category') );
        $type = str_replace( '+', ' ', $this->input->post('type') );
        $description = $this->input->post('description');
        $extract = $this->input->post('extract');           
        $date = time();
        $link = $this->input->post('link');

        if($this->input->post('closing_date')){
            $closing_date = $this->input->post('closing_date');
            $closing_date = str_replace('/', '-', $closing_date);
            $closing_date = strtotime($closing_date);
        }else{
            $closing_date = time() + 2592000;
        }

        $url = str_replace(' ', '-', trim($role));
        $location_dash = str_replace(' ', '-', trim($location));
        $url = $url."-in-".$location_dash;

        $this->db->set('role', $role);
        $this->db->set('company', $company);
        $this->db->set('type', $type);
        $this->db->set('location', $location);
        $this->db->set('category', $category);
        $this->db->set('url', strtolower($url));            
        $this->db->set('description', $description);
        $this->db->set('extract', $extract);            
        $this->db->set('link', $link);          
        $this->db->set('time', $date);
        $this->db->set('closing_date', $closing_date);
        $this->db->set('active', 1);

        $this->db->insert('jobs');  

        $job = $this->db->get_where('jobs', array('time' => $date ))->row_array();

        $url = "http://www.example.com/job/view/".$job['id']."/".$job['url']."";

        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
          'appId'  => '***',
          'secret' => '***'
        ));

        $message = array(
        'access_token' => "***",
        'message'=> "".$url.""
        );

        $facebook->api('/me/accounts','POST', $message);
```

Comment: _“I know the problem is something to do with the fact my access token is wrong”_ – and so you thought it’d be nice to show as a long bit of uninteresting code, anything _except_ for how you’re getting that access token …?

Comment: @CBroe I'm currently getting my access_token from here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/accounts but unsure if I' getting the right access code

Comment: You have to get that token using your own app in the Graph API Explorer (chose from dropdown on top), otherwise it will be for the GAE app and therefor will not match your app_id/app_secret.

Comment: @CBroe I've just done this but having a hard time getting the access_token that I haven't already used. Does something like this look about right `CAADCYgHCblaBADcKoJeZApU54E44Iz17tsniCFozTATKZAK7JLPWA6oblaOTvNRaWm69RP43XblayVkdmVH6iqblaiXyJnXqzbU8pfOjMieblaRDn25IHmHkuukZblasFDV81RewAXq19xJLRTi9G5iblabla`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How have you logged in with Facebook from your website? You need to make sure that you use

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_actions'));
```

`publish_actions` scope allows your application to make posts on the users behalf

Then use:

```
$message = array(
    'access_token' => $facebook->getAccessToken(), // Get current access_token
    'message'=> "".$url.""
);

$facebook->api('/me/accounts','POST', $message);
```

And it should post successfully

Hope that solves the problem!